# curl_exec return value not containing hidden field value

Tags: curl, field, hidden

When viewing the 'Elements' in Chrome tools, the following HTML elements are there:

```
<input id="dna" name="dna" type="hidden" value="some long string..."/>
```

but when viewing the code after doing a curl_exec(...) on the url, and parsing the result, I see the following:

```
<input id="dna" name="dna" type="hidden"/>
```

with no value="...". Am I missing something? Essentially I need the value of the hidden field.

Comment: Maybe the value of the hidden field is populated client-side with Javascript?  I'd look for signs of that and see if it is the case.

Comment: That would mean running the javascript, populating _POSTFIELDS and then curl_exec. Question is, how do you run a javascript function - phantomjs?

Comment: Hang on. The value is already there before I submit the form. As I said above, when inspecting it in chrome, the value is there when served by the host to my browser.

Comment: So under Chrome Elements the hidden values are all there. Surely those are accessible in the DOM object? Any idea why this value is not returned by curl_exec?

Comment: If the hidden values are populated by Javascript they would show up as such in the chrome inspector.  Try disabling Javascript and then see if they're populated, or view source on the page in Chrome.  I don't think it would show JS populated data, only the original source at the time of page load.